# Remove all entries in all tables with one query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a single SQL statement that I can use to delete all the entries from a database?

I want an SQL statement equivalent to running the `DELETE FROM tbl_name;` on all the tables in the database.

If such a statement doesn't exist, why not? It seems like something people would want to do.

Comment: Why would you want to completely empty your entire database?

Comment: BTW, `TRUNCATE tbl_name` is a better way to empty a table.

Comment: Im creating a database frontend, and want to provide administrators with the ability to reset the database to default.